# Search for Twitter handles using Google Apps Script and Twitter API - doesn't work

Tags: twitter, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find Twitter handles from a spreadsheet containing names of people.

I can't get it work with this request, which I believe is the one I should be using as I only have peoples names (e.g. Adam Smith):  api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=

I get the following error:

> Request failed for api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=Name    returned code 403. Truncated server response:  {"errors":[{"message":"Your credentials do not allow access to this  resource","code":220}]} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 38).'

I've tried searching this error but that hasn't helped me so far.

If I use, for example, this request, it works: api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=

So I can get the screen_name back in the spreadsheet, but that's pointless obviously because it needs the screen name to work in the first place...

The whole thing is based on [this work](https://gist.github.com/laurenancona/1f3b8ce7a50e7d24ad04adccebce3fa3), all the requests in that code work for me. It's just this search request that doesn't work. What's going wrong?

```
var CONSUMER_KEY = 'x';
var CONSUMER_SECRET =   'x';


function getTwitterHandles(name) {

// Encode consumer key and secret
var tokenUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
var tokenCredential = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(
CONSUMER_KEY + ":" + CONSUMER_SECRET);

 //  Obtain a bearer token with HTTP POST request
 var tokenOptions = {
headers : {
 Authorization: "Basic " + tokenCredential,
 "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" 
 },
 method: "post",
 payload: "grant_type=client_credentials"
 };

 var responseToken = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tokenUrl, tokenOptions);
 var parsedToken = JSON.parse(responseToken);
 var token = parsedToken.access_token;

 // Authenticate Twitter API requests with the bearer token
 var apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=screen_name='+name;
var apiOptions = {
headers : {
 Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
},
"method" : "get"
};

var responseApi = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, apiOptions);
var result = "";
if (responseApi.getResponseCode() == 200) {

// Parse the JSON encoded Twitter API response
var tweets = JSON.parse(responseApi.getContentText());
return tweets.id
}
Logger.log(result);
}
```

Edit: deleted the https a few times because of the URL limit

Answer (score 0):

You can not search for users using application-only authentication (bearer token). See https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only. A user context (access token) is needed for that request. You can get your own access token from https://apps.twitter.com.

Comment: I see, thanks! I'm struggling to find examples of how to do this in GAS though so might have to abandon this idea.